# Apagar dois ID's de tabelas diferentes na mesma query

Tags: php, mysql, query

Boa tarde!

Eu tenho duas tabelas: **1ª questionario** e  **2ª resposta**, e **pergunta_id** é a chave que permite interligar as duas tabelas, sendo a `foreign key` na tabela "resposta" da tabela "questionario".

Quando insiro um registo, eu não consigo apagar o registo primeiramente da tabela "questionario", mas sim primeiro da tabela "comentario".

Como desenvolvi uma página o administrador pode ver todos os resultados da base de dados, e manipulá-los. Uma das opções é eliminar os resultados , porém não estou a conseguir fazer **uma** `query` que permita eliminar das tuas tabelas o último ID...

O ID eu pego pelo URL:

`$resposta_id = $_GET['resposta_id'];`

mas somente o ID da resposta "`$resposta_id`", na `query` pensei pegar de alguma forma o último ID da tabela "questionario" de forma decrescente, porém não consegui formar uma `query` só com isso tudo, e para a junção das tabelas eu tinha feito: 
 
`select * from questionario left join resposta on questionario.pergunta_id=resposta.pergunta_id`

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como fazer, ou até mesmo de outra maneira agradeço!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer excluir todos os registros das duas tabelas? Ou apenas o ultimo registro de cada tabela?

Comment: No caso o ID de ambos é pergunta_id, ao excluir uma você quer deletar das duas tabelas?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro peço desculpa, quero apagar o último registo de cada tabela, como eu referi "o último ID"

Comment: @MauroAlexandre isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que `pergunta_id` seja um `fk` das tabelas, você pode fazer um `INNER JOIN` diretamente no `delete`.

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1
    INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t2.ref = t1.id
```

Nesse exemplo ele vai deletar todos os registros onde `t2.ref` seja igual a `t1.id`.

Tendo o valor de `pergunta_id` basta acrescentar a cláusula `WHERE`

```
DELETE t1,t2 FROM t1
    INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t2.ref = t1.id 
    WHERE t1.id = '{pergunta_id}'
```

Veja a query em funcionamento: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a64b/2

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, assim que puder eu vou testar o código!

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada fiz assim `$apagar="DELETE resposta, questionario from resposta
 INNER JOIN
 questionario ON questionario.pergunta_id = resposta.pergunta_id
 WHERE
 resposta.resposta_id = '".$resposta_id."'";`